# Realm classes not instantiated inside a block

Tags: ios, parse-platform, realm

I'm querying a Parse endpoint `News`, and then attempting to convert the returned objects into the `RLMOBject` subclass object `NewsObject`, in order to save them to my Realm DB.

Problem is, my data is properly fetched and displayed in the tableview, however, `newsObj` is not created! (further, the `NSLog` statement following it is never executed).

To make this more peculiar; Whenever I go back to the previous view, and then re-access this one, `newsObj` IS instantiated, and the `NSLog` executed normally!!

On a side note, attempting to even instantiate the `defaultRealm` will create similar issues.

Below is the simplified *(equally as broken)* version of my full code, running in `viewDidLoad`.

```
     //--- Query Parse for News entry ---   
     PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];

     [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        self.dataSourceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        //--- Create RLMObject NewsObject ---    
        NewsObject *newsObj = [NewsObject new];
        NSLog(@"NewsObject Created");
     }];
```

**UPDATE:**

Turns out there were a couple of un-thrown errors occurring.

1) REALM objects shouldn't be created/updated on background threads.

2) Any errors with the REALM object itself, will not get thrown on this PARSE background thread.

I first had to dispatch creating `NewsObject` on the main thread, then an error concerning using `NSNumber` properties in my `RLMObject` model showed up. I fixed those, and got the solution working!

Here's how my code looks now;

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];

  [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

     if (!error) {

          //--- Create RLMObject on Main Thread ---    
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                NewsObject *newsObj = [NewsObject new];
                NSLog(@"NewsObject Created");

                self.dataSourceArray = [NewsObject allObjects];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
          });   
      }
  }];
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it to see what's going on?

Comment: Of course! It's the same behaviour... Setting up a breakpoint, just before the NewsObject line, stepping INTO or OVER that line, resumes program execution normally, as if the line didn't exist the first time that ViewController is loaded. Go back, then access it again, and the lines execute normally now...

Comment: Did the block inside execute? Make a break point on `NSLog(@"NewsObject Created");` and send it over please.

Comment: The block always executes normally, up to that NewsObject line. Setting a breakpoint at the NSLog line simply doesn't make the app break the first time I access the ViewController. Put that breakpoint a couple of lines above, and it works like a charm.

Comment: try to put `self.dataSourceArray` assignment and `[self.tableView reloadData]` after the NSLog. Try to dispatch it to the main thread

Comment: @Priest what is being displayed in stack trace (left pane) ?

Comment: It may be thrown a exception when initializing Realm, but Parse is catching that exception and not rethrowing it unfortunately. (To be strict, Bolts framework that Parse used catch all exceptions and ignore) To be sure, what happens if you execute `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]` outside the block and before using Parse? I think exception is thrown by Realm.

Comment: Hey guys, I've actually solved the problem, and just updated my answer to reflect it.
Thanks for the useful hints, they really pushed me in the right direction! :)